# how to remove the white space that appears below the uitableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, scroll

As shown in the [figure]

[image: figure]

when I scroll down to the end appears a large block with nothing, How to remove this and scroll the scroll only until the end of **UiTableView** content?

the following images describe the configuration of my uitableview in the storyboard:[storyboar_one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U0iR.png), [storyboard_two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAADs.png), [storyboard_three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaFWe.png)

this my viewDidLoad Method:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    let nib: UINib = UINib(nibName: "ObrigacaoTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
}
```

Comment: you can resize your table view according to its content size

Comment: try to use this code: self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

Comment: just resize your table according to content in it. like @RahulGUsai said above.

Comment: @RahulGUsai can you demonstrate please?

Comment: you can calculate your table view contentsize by tableview.contentSize.height and you have to assign it to the constraint outlet of your table view and you have to repeat it each time you deque a cell

Answer (score 1):

Try `self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`

Because the table thinks there is a footer to show, it doesn't display any cells beyond those you explicitly asked for therefore it shows up as a blank space.

Also make sure the bottom edge inset of UITableView is 0

Answer (score 0):

To remove blank cells in the table keep the below code in viewDidLoad() method after estimatedHeight,

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove empty cells in UITableView

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```